# Missing fields in google service account JSON error while using admin firebase SDK

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sdk, admin

I am trying to implement real time database of firebase using Kraet admin SDK for PHP 7.0.
I have installed composer and all the dependencies required for the implementation, but I am facing one error like

```
**Fatal error: Uncaught Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
/var/www/html/cabgotel/google-service-account.json could not be parsed to a Service Account:
The following fields are missing/empty in the Service Account specification:
project_id, client_id, client_email, private_key in /var/www/html/cabgotel/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/ServiceAccount.php:164 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/cabgotel/firebase.php(42): Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('/var/www/html/c...')
#1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/cabgotel/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/ServiceAccount.php on line 164**
```

I have downloaded the service account json file and added it in the same directory. And I even checked the values inside the file to know whether this is for the same firebase project.

Following is the code I am using for this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>


<script>

  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCfGmNSdx5uabtQMGgEjtcz_BL8y_Tm4II",
    authDomain: "auth_domain",
    databaseURL: "my_db_url",
    projectId: "my_project_id",
    storageBucket: "my_project_id_storage_bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "sender_id"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

// This assumes that you have placed the Firebase credentials in the same directory
// as this PHP file.
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://my_project.firebaseio.com')
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

$newPost = $database
    ->getReference('https://my_project.firebaseio.com')
    ->push([
        'lan' => '10.77',
        'lat' => '88.99'
    ]);

$newPost->getKey(); // => -KVr5eu8gcTv7_AHb-3-
$newPost->getUri(); // => https://my-project.firebaseio.com/blog/posts/-KVr5eu8gcTv7_AHb-3-

$newPost->getChild('lan')->set('11.211');
$newPost->getValue(); // Fetches the data from the realtime database
$newPost->remove();
```

Please help.

Comment: The error message to me reads like the code can fine the file, but can't find some required fields *inside* the file. Are you sure you download the *service account* and not `google-services.json` (as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app))?

Comment: I downloaded google -services.json from firebase and used that

Comment: I thought they are both one and same

Comment: There are two files, and they are *quite* different: 1) `google-services.json` is for use in Android apps that you send to your users, and merely contains configuration data that the Firebase client SDKs use to find the project on Google's servers. 2) the service account JSON, which contains a public and private key pair that allows the code administrative (=unrestricted) access to your project.

Comment: Okay can you please tell me where I can find the service account JSON file with public and private key?

Comment: You can download it from the Service Accounts tab in the Firebase console. I included the link in my first comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You should post your last comment as an answer so that I can upvote it :). The link you posted is also part of the setup instructions in the PHP SDK‘s docs at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two files, and they are quite different:

1. The `google-services.json` is for use in Android apps that you send to your users, and merely contains configuration data that the Firebase client SDKs use to find the project on Google's servers.
2. The service account JSON, which contains a public and private key pair that allows the code administrative (unrestricted) access to your project.

The error message to me reads like the code *can* find the file, but *can't* find some required fields inside the file. May sure you download the service account JSON from the Service Accounts tab in the Firebase console, as shown in the documentation on [adding Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Frank! I stole your last sentence  to [improve the error message in the PHP SDK](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/commit/9d5422ed869ff71ce9eeeb6c348c0c9fefa067b5) and created a new release so that developers can benefit from this from now on: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/releases/tag/4.19.1 Thank you for all the support you're providing here on SO!

Comment: Thanks for improving the PHP SDK for Firebase Jerome!